# react web app conditional app loading not working

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react and was able to set upa . react project using create-react-app. Now I am trying to learn to add spinner when user enter the keyword and it has to wait for some time to load the result.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = { result: [] ,loading:null};

    OnSearchSubmit = async (email) =>{
       this.state.loading = true;
       try 
       {
           const response =  await fetch(‘/info’,{
            method:'post',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
            });
            const body = await response.json();      
            this.setState({loading:false,  result: body});
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    };
     render (){
        return (
            <div className="ui container" style={{ marginTop: '10px'}}>
                <SearchBar onSubmit={this.OnSearchSubmit}/>
                {
                     this.state.loading === true ? 
                     <LoadingSpinner/> : 
                    <PrjList plist={result}/>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

When results arrive it list me plist items. But it is not showing waiting spinner. I have tracked the status.loader value and it is correctly showing the change in values but it is not showing the spinner. Can someone find what I might be overlooking

[tutorial followed for adding spinner](https://blog.stvmlbrn.com/2017/10/14/display-loading-indicator-in-react-during-ajax-requests.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update the component state, you should use [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

```
/* ... */
state = { result: [] ,loading: false};

    OnSearchSubmit = async (email) =>{
       /* HERE */
       this.setState({ loading: true });

       try 
       {
           const response =  await fetch(‘/info’,{
            method:'post',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
            });
            const body = await response.json();      
            this.setState({loading:false,  result: body});
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    };

/* ... */
```

Be in mind that setState is asynchronous so, you could improve this code calling a method after the setState ends:

```
OnSearchSubmit = email => {
  this.setState({ loading: true }, () => { this.fetchInfo(email) });
}

fetchInfo = email => {
  try {
    /* ... rest of the code */
  } catch...
}
```

Comment: The [doc link](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) where it's explained how to use setState